# How to set delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I have this simple class

**TestViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ClassB.h"

@protocol TestViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)hello;

@end

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic , weak) id<TestViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /******* WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?!?? *****/

    [self.delegate hello];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

And another class:

**ClassB.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface ClassB : NSObject <TestViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
#import "ClassB.h"
@implementation ClassB

-(void)hello
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO!");
}

@end
```

Now I need to create and instance of ClassB and set this instance as the delegate of TestViewContoller, but I can't figure out what I need to write!
Can You help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written there is correct. The only other thing you need to do is set ClassB as the delegate of TestViewController. One way that's commonly done is for ClassB to instantiate TestViewController, then set itself as the delegate:

In ClassB:

```
TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
test.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Where should I add this two line of code? In which method of ClassB?

Comment: Wherever you need to. It depends on when you need to instantiate TestViewController.

Comment: mmmh.. In this case I can't write these lines of code in the Hello method. And do I need to create in instance of ClassB in my TestViewController's viewDidLoad method? In your opinion, how can I modify my code for do this?

Comment: Same with the [self.delegate hello]; line in TestViewController -- that can go anywhere that it makes sense to call that method.

Comment: What do you mean be "I can't write these lines of code in the Hello method" -- I don't understand. And, no, you don't need to instantiate ClassB in TestViewController -- in fact, the delegating class doesn't need to know anything about the class that implements the delegate protocol. That's kind of the whole point of delegates.

Comment: Yes, but my ClassB isn't a ViewController, so, It hasn't a ViewDidLoad method, but only one method which is "hello".

Comment: And do I need to create a Instance of ClassB in my testViewController?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17985/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mutexmark)